# How to plot JUST linear regression without data?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to decompose R use-cases into simple building bricks.

I found an example with linear regression.

```
data(cars)
m <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)
plot(dist ~ speed, data=cars)
abline(m)
```

I got 2 charts. If I run just `abline(m)` I get white window.
Maybe it is not practical at all, but I feel constrained.

Hack with `plot(c() ~ c())` doesn't show m chart.

Answer (score 2):

The plot command does more than just adding the points, it sets up the axes as well, so you need to keep that using the data, but can use the argument `type='n'` to skip plotting the points. See `?plot.default` for all the possible values of the argument `type`.

```
data(cars)
m <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)
plot(dist ~ speed, data=cars, type='n')
abline(m)
```